# Creating a win32 modal window with CreateWindow

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, modal-dialog

I create a window with `CreateWindow()` and show it with `ShowWindow()`. But the parent window on which this was created should be disabled until user returns from this window, i.e. it should simulate modal dialog box.

Answer (score 23):

Make sure you set the `hwndParent` in `CreateWindow` and use `EnableWindow(hwndParent, FALSE)` to disable the parent after showing the pop up window. Then enable the parent with `EnableWindow(hwndParent, TRUE)` after the pop up window has been closed.

Comment: You have to `EnableWindow(hwndParent, TRUE)` *before* the popup window is closed, see [The correct order for disabling and enabling windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/27/81155.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Link broken, new link is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463

Answer (score 14):

[Modality, part 1: UI-modality vs code-modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050218-00/?p=36413) explains how to do this, and why you might not want to.

Comment: Old New Thing references are great, but too bad it's a link only answer. You might want to rephrase some content from the article in your own words.

Answer (score 4):

You need to consider what it means to be a modal window - basically, the window's parent is disabled. The only automatic way of doing this (that I am aware of) is to call `DialogBox()` to create a modal dialog box. However, since you want to use `CreateWindow()`, then all that you need to do is to manually disable the parent window yourself.

Ideally, it would be better to go the dialog box route (since the OS knows exactly what must be done in order to create a modal window), but I suppose this option is there if you must use it.

Answer (score 3):

You could also run a "secondary message loop" which keeps the parent window inactive till your work with the "modal" dialog is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I just wrestled with this same problem myself.  I needed a quick dialog that behaved like it would if I used DialogBox() but I didn't want to create a template for the particular project I was using.

What I discovered is that if you disable the parent window of the dialog you also disable the dialog.  And you can't enable that dialog without re-enabling the parent dialog.  So that method won't work.

I also discovered that you can't use SetCapture() / ReleaseCapture() because then the child windows of the dialog won't get messages.

I did find a solution that works:  Use a local message pump, driven by either PeekMessage() or GetMessage().  Here is the code that worked for me:

```
  while (!m_bFinished)
  {
     BOOL bEat;

     if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
     {
        if (msg.message == WM_CHAR)
        {
           if (msg.wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
           {
              m_bFinished = TRUE;
              continue;
           }
        }

        bEat = FALSE;

        if (msg.message >= WM_MOUSEFIRST &&
           msg.message <= WM_MOUSELAST)
        {
           RECT rectMe;

           pcMe->GetWindowRect(&rectMe);
           if (!::PtInRect(&rectMe, msg.pt))
              bEat = TRUE;
        }

        if (!bEat)
        {
           ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
           ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
     }
  }
```

What this effectively does is "eat" any mouse messages that are outside the client area of the window for all messages delivered to that application.  It does not prohibit clicking outside the application, just clicking anywhere inside the application that isn't within the client area of the "modal" window.  If you add a MessageBeep() when you eat a message you'll get the exact same behavior as a real modal dialog.

m_bFinished is a BOOL member of the class and it gets set if either the OK or Cancel buttons are accessed on the "dialog," and under certain other conditions that are outside the scope of the code snippet here.